# show error message on jQuery-UI dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Rails** app. My simple code is showing below:

The **model**:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::BaseWithoutTable
   validates_presence_of :brand
end
```

The **controller**:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
   def check
      @user_car = Car.new(params[:car]);
      if(@user_car.valid?)
   end
end
```

The **view**:

```
<div id="car_check">
<% form_for :car, Car.new(), :url => "car/check" do |f| %>
  <% if flash[:error] %>
      <h2><%= flash[:error] %></h2>
  <%end%>
  ...
<%= f.submit "send" %>
</div>
```

The above form `div` will be opened in a **jQuery-ui** `dialog`, like following:

```
$("#car_check").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    modal: true
  });
```

When user submit the `car` model form with **invalid** data, I'd like to show the **error message** on the **jQuery-ui** `dialog`, however, the `dialog` get closed when form "`submit`" button pressed, which makes user **can not see the error message**. **How to get rid of it?**

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function that's called when the user clicks on the submit button must return a boolean false when an error occurs, otherwise the form is submitted once the function returns.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function errorCheck()
{
  if (document.getElementById('mystring').value == 'error'
  {
     /* The user typed in "error" */
     return false;
  }
  else
  {
     /* For anything else */
     return false;
  }
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="mystring" id="mystring">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="errorCheck()">
</form>
```

[This post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/58777#638112) might help you with the Ruby code. I'm not a Ruby programmer so this is just what I found by searching around a bit.